MSOFFICE Excel settings
I am a user living in Korea.
In Excel’s page settings, select the dialog box menu.
Can I add it like the attached file below?
I'm asking a question because I'm curious.
thank you
I wish you good luck always.

PLEASE
MAKE IT


When printing in Excel, how do I repeatedly insert specific cell values ​​and lines (data rows) in multiple rows at the bottom of each page?
I would like to have a specific row printed repeatedly at the bottom of each page, like a footer.
Or is it possible to implement specific cell values ​​and lines in the footer as is?
